# How to set up CNAME to point to Azure

Tags: cname-record, azure, a-record

Here's the story. I have an application on azure. I would like to set up an A-record. My main domain is myhost.dk and my azure adress is myhost.azurewebsites.net. The Azure guide says that I have to set up a CNAME with awverify.myhost.dk to point to awverify.myhost.azurewebsites.net  before I can create an A record. No idea what that awverify is for. I'm really confused. My DNS management panel is not very informative, and im very confused about where to put all the data.

I know there not much to go on, but I recon there's people out there that's done this a million time.

To be specific. What do I put in CNAME "host" and "canonical name"?

Ps. Sorry if this is the wrong StackExchange site to post this on.

Answer (score 4):

From the [documentation](http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/develop/net/common-tasks/custom-dns-web-site/):

> To configure an A record you must configure a CNAME record used to verify the domain name. This process is the same as one used to configure a CNAME record to point at to your web site, except that you configure the CNAME record domain names that will be used for verification purposes.

The `awverify` record is so that Azure can confirm that you control the domain name, and want it linked to a specific site. You need to create two records in your DNS:

```
awverify.myhost.dk  CNAME   awverify.myhost.azurewebsites.net
myhost.dk       A       1.2.3.4
```

Comment: Hey mate. My problem wasn't solved :( I've added a comment to larsks answer.

Answer (score 2):

A `CNAME` is a pointer from one domain name (the "canonical name") to another domain name.  So for example, if you wanted to make `myhost.dk` point to `myhost.azurewebsites.net` you would need to create a `CNAME` with `myhost.dk` as the canonical name and `myhost.azurewebsites.net` as the host.

Azure first requires to you set up `awverify.myhost.dk` to verify that you own and control the `myhost.dk` domain. Other services (e.g., Google Apps) perform similar validation to verify domain ownership.  For this, `awverify.myhost.dk` would be the canonical name and `awverify.myhost.azurewebsites.net` would be the host.

After creating this record, you should be able to use your favorite DNS lookup tool to verify that the record exists.  Something like:

```
$ host -t cname www.example.com
www.example.com is an alias for example.myhost.azurewebsites.net.
```

Comment: Right. Thanks mate. Makes sense. I will accept the other answer though as he was first :)

Comment: @KasperSkov larsks was first actually, he just did an edit shortly after.

Comment: Eh, whatever.  They're both good answers.

Comment: Right. The answer made sense and I thought I could pull it off. But my DNS setup thingo wont play along. Do I create 2 primary DNS setup for each myhost.dk and myhost.eatart.dk and setup a CNAME on the awverify and an ARecord on myhost.dk? If I create a new DNS setup for the awverify one it just says: The domain is not valid or it is not FQDN (fully Qualifyed Domain Name). What does that mean?

Comment: It sounds like maybe you need to contact support at your hosting company.